# Create surface by combining 2D curves

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to create a plot in which I look at the change of a curve as a function of a parameter.

My problem is quite complicated so below you can see a simplifying example

```
    Table[ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + 1/A) Cos[\[Theta]], (1 + 1/
      A) Sin[\[Theta]], A}, {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {A, 0.5, 1, 0.1}]
```

[image]

I wish to make from these curves a continous surface (in this case it will be a something like a cone).

In my original problem these curves are parts of solutions for and ODE so just plotting the shape I want will not solve the problem here, therefore I ask for an answer that will generically create a surface out of the combination of these curves.

**Update:**

Here is an out line of what I'm trying to do with the problem I'm working on:

I have a 2D dynamical system that undergoes a hopf bifurcations as the parameter `A` is varied.

```
  f[x_, y_, A_] := 
  10 - 0.05 (x - 1) (1 + 1/A + 1/y Exp[(2 (x - 1))/(10 y)] )  ;  
g[x_, y_, A_] := A (1 - y) - y Exp[(2 (x - 1))/(10 y)];
```

I solve the equations for large `t` to guarantee that the solution converges either to a stable fixed point or into a limit cycle

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t], 1], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t], 1], x[0] == 0.2,
     y[0] == 0.2}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 50}];
sol2 = NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t], 2], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t], 2], x[0] == 0.2,
     y[0] == 0.2}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 50}];
sol3 = NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t], 3], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t], 3], x[0] == 0.2,
     y[0] == 0.2}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 50}];
sol4 = NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t], 4], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t], 4], x[0] == 0.2,
     y[0] == 0.2}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 50}];
```

I pick the last part of the solution (the end of the time series) and plot it with a `ParametricPlot3D`

```
p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{Evaluate[x[t]], Evaluate[y[t]], 1} /. sol1, {t,
     49, 50}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotPoints -> 10^5, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}, {0, 10}}];
p2 = ParametricPlot3D[{Evaluate[x[t]], Evaluate[y[t]], 2} /. sol2, {t,
     49, 50}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotPoints -> 10^5, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}, {0, 10}}];
p3 = ParametricPlot3D[{Evaluate[x[t]], Evaluate[y[t]], 3} /. sol3, {t,
     49, 50}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotPoints -> 10^5, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0,10}, {0, 1}, {0, 10}}];
p4 = ParametricPlot3D[{Evaluate[x[t]], Evaluate[y[t]], 4} /. sol4, {t,
     49, 50}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotPoints -> 10^5, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0,10}, {0, 1}, {0, 10}}];
```

Put all of the plots together

```
   Show[p1, p2, p3, p4]
```

What I'd like to obtain is a continuous surface (small increments of `A`) that passes through these contours as stated in the original question.

Comment: why not `ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + 1/A) Cos[\[Theta]], (1 + 1/A) Sin[\[Theta]], 
  A}, {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {A, 0.5, 1}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]`?

Comment: @kglr, in my problem for each value of 'A'  I have a different solution produced by NDSolve

Comment: jarhead, have you tried `ParametricNDSolveValue`?

Comment: jarhead, what is `lf`?

Comment: @kglr, sorry it is a number, corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use two-parameter version of `ParametricPlot3D` to get the desired surface:

```
 ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + 1/A) Cos[θ], (1 + 1/A) Sin[θ], A}, 
   {θ, -π, π}, {A, 0.5, 3}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#5 &}, 
  Mesh -> {Range[ 0.5, 3, .1]}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None,
  BoxRatios ->1, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, combine all plots using `Show`, extract line coordinates and use them  with `ListPlot3D`:

```
show = Show[Table[ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + 1/A) Cos[θ], (1 + 1/A) Sin[θ], A}, {θ, -π, π}, 
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, PlotPoints -> 100],
   {A, 0.5, 3, 0.1}]];

pts = Join @@ Cases[show, Line[x_] :> x, {0, Infinity}];

Show[ListPlot3D[pts, Mesh -> None, ClippingStyle -> None, 
    PlotRange -> {-5, 2.99}], PlotRange->{-5,5}, BoxRatios->1]
```

[image]

A slower alternative is to use `ListSurfacePlot3D`:

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[pts, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, MaxPlotPoints -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: this is extremely slow

Comment: @jarhead, `ListSurfacePlot3D` is slow. But in the first 2, additional processing (above what you need to create lines with one-parameter `ParamatricPlot3D`) is not too exorbitant. It would help to post an example that reflects  your real case.

Comment: I've added an example that reflects the real case in the question, emphasizing the steps of what I want to do.